# Unknown Column Error when using custom column name for email - Laravel Fortify

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

I have a database with a column named `mail` for the users table, but in Laravel it's `email`. My problem is now the forgot-password function.

I will always get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
1048 Column 'email' cannot be null 
(SQL: insert into `password_resets` (`email`, `token`, `created_at`) values 
(?, $2y$10$....., 2022-01-03 16:55:22))
```

I created a custom route for forgot-password, but that's not working somehow.

`````
Route::post('/forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
    
    $request->validate([
        'mail' => ['required', 'email'],
        'username' => ['required'],
    ]);
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('username', 'mail')
    );
    
    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])
        : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
})->middleware('guest')->name('password.mail');````
`````

In the *fortify.php* I set `'email' => 'mail',` but there is no difference.
Maybe I did something extremely dumb, but I'm new to Laravel.

So how can I fix this?

It's not possible to rename the mail column to email and it would be dumb to create a second column in the users table that's just named email with the same content.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `getEmailForPasswordReset` method on the model you are trying to use. The Token Repository will ask the model for the value of what ever the email field is by calling `getEmailForPasswordReset` on the model.

```
public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
{
    return $this->mail;
}
```